How to drag several objects together with react-draggable?
I use react-draggable in my project. It helps to visualize some data as tables (draggable tables) collected in a diagram. Now I can move (drag) only one table at a time, but we want to choose some tables and drag them together. Has anyone tried to make the same feature with this library?
Here's a part of my code:
<Draggable
                onDrag={onDrag}
                onStop={onChangePositionHandler}
                nodeRef={nodeRef}
                position={{ x: table.position.x, y: table.position.y }}
                zIndex="8"
            >
                <div
                    className={styles.MainContainer}
                    id={table.name}
                >
                {table.name}
               </div>
            </Draggable>

And a function for moving a table to save it's coordinates later:
const onChangePositionHandler = (event, dragElement) => {
        onStop();
        const changedTable = {
            id: table.id,
            name: table.name,
            isCreatedByUser: table.isCreatedByUser,
            isAssociator: table.isAssociator,
            color: tableColor,
            position: {
                x: dragElement.x,
                y: dragElement.y
            },
            columns: table.columns
        };

        onChangeTableHandler(changedTable, areaName);
    };

I found one answer which is close (How to drag multiple objects at once in React?), but all of the tables should drag.
I can put selected tables in a new array, but how to find new coordinates for each after dragging?
